# Fill a select options with Select2 Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 Ajax to apply autocomplete on my html select

this is the select2 code :

```
        <script>
            $(function(){
            $(".marques-multi").select2({
                minimumInputLength: 3,
                tags: [],
                ajax: {
                    url: "user/marques",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "GET",
                    quietMillis: 50,
                    data: function (term) {
                        return term;
                    },
                      processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                          results: data
                        };
                    },
                    transport: function (params, success, failure) {
                        var $request = $.ajax(params);

                        $request.then(success);
                        $request.fail(failure);

                        return $request;
                  }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and this is my html :

```
    <select class="form-control input-sm marques-multi" name="marque"></select>
```

and this is what the URL : "user/marques" with the data (www.mywebsite.com/user/marques/marques?term=nike) returns :

```
[
{"id_marque":"50670","marque_name":"NIK HUBER GUITARS"},{"id_marque":"50671","marque_name":"NIKALAS CATLOW"},{"id_marque":"1","marque_name":"NIKE"},{"id_marque":"50672","marque_name":"NIKE"},
{"id_marque":"50673","marque_name":"NIKE"},{"id_marque":"50674","marque_name":"NIKE 6.0"},{"id_marque":"50675","marque_name":"NIKE ACCESSORIES"},{"id_marque":"50676","marque_name":"NIKE ACG"},{"id_marque":"50677","marque_name":"NIKE ACTION SPORTS"},{"id_marque":"50678","marque_name":"NIKE AIR MAX"},{"id_marque":"50679","marque_name":"NIKE BAIN"}
]
```

when I write as example nik in the select input i see in the console that the requests returns this json bellow with no errors but the select doesn't get fill with this data it stays blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, change your data properties on JSON from `id_marque` and `marque_name` to `id` and `text` instead.

**So from:**

```
[
{"id_marque":"50670","marque_name":"NIK HUBER GUITARS"},{"id_marque":"50671","marque_name":"NIKALAS CATLOW"},{"id_marque":"1","marque_name":"NIKE"},{"id_marque":"50672","marque_name":"NIKE"},
{"id_marque":"50673","marque_name":"NIKE"},{"id_marque":"50674","marque_name":"NIKE 6.0"},{"id_marque":"50675","marque_name":"NIKE ACCESSORIES"},{"id_marque":"50676","marque_name":"NIKE ACG"},{"id_marque":"50677","marque_name":"NIKE ACTION SPORTS"},{"id_marque":"50678","marque_name":"NIKE AIR MAX"},{"id_marque":"50679","marque_name":"NIKE BAIN"}
]
```

**To:**

```
[{"id":"50670","text":"NIK HUBER GUITARS"},{"id":"50671","text":"NIKALAS CATLOW"},{"id":"1","text":"NIKE"},{"id":"50672","text":"NIKE"},
    {"id":"50673","text":"NIKE"},{"id":"50674","text":"NIKE 6.0"},{"id":"50675","text":"NIKE ACCESSORIES"},{"id":"50676","text":"NIKE ACG"},{"id":"50677","text":"NIKE ACTION SPORTS"},{"id":"50678","text":"NIKE AIR MAX"},{"id":"50679","text":"NIKE BAIN"}];
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrtd5at7/)

Comment: doesn"t work stayed the same error .. but I did a jquery ui autocomplete instead ...

thank you.

Comment: @ADiL What errors are you seeing? But if you already made it work, no need to answer me.